# six orthogonal vectors as the displacements resulted from applying rigid transformations (three translations & three rotations) to a set of points

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, rigid-transformation

Given N points represented by a $N\times 3$ matrix:
$$ P=
\begin{bmatrix}
P_{11} & P_{12} & P_{13} \\
P_{21} & P_{22} & P_{23} \\
P_{31} & P_{32} & P_{33} \\
\cdots & \cdots  & \cdots  \\
P_{N1} & P_{N2} & P_{N3} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where the $i$th row $P_i$ contains three coordinates of the $i$th point.

A **rigid transformation** preserves the Euclidean distance between every pair of points. The well-known rigid transformations include **translations** (along the x,y, and z-axis) and **rotations** (around x,y,and z-axis).

I am looking for **six orthogonal vectors** (dimension: $3N$ ) **as the displacements resulted from applying rigid transformations** (three translations & three rotations) **to N points**. I tried two approaches, the first is analytically false, and the second is not solvable by numeric method.

**1. Trivial approach**

Applying along x-axis translations and subtracting the original values results in $P^X$, each row
$$
P^X_i = [P_{i1} +1,P_{i2},P_{i3} ]- P_i = [1,0,0]
$$
y-axis translations results in $P^Y$, each row $P^Y_i = [0,1,0 ]$

z-axis translations results in $P^Z$, each row $P^Z_i = [0,0,1 ]$

One can rewrite matrix $P^X$ into a vector $\mathbf{p}^X$ (representing the displacements after transformation),
$$
\mathbf{p}^X=\begin{bmatrix} P^X_{11} \\ P^X_{12}\\ P^X_{13}\\ P^X_{21} \\ P^X_{22}\\ P^X_{23}\\ \dots \\ P^X_{N1} \\ P^X_{N2}\\ P^X_{N3}\\ \end{bmatrix}
$$

while $\mathbf{p}^Y$ and $\mathbf{p}^Z$ are defined likewise. Then $ \mathbf{p}^X \cdot \mathbf{p}^Y = \mathbf{p}^X \cdot \mathbf{p}^Z=\mathbf{p}^Y \cdot \mathbf{p}^Z=0$ holds, i.e., the three vectors are orthogonal.

Applying around x-axis translations and subtracting the original values results in $P^A$, each row
$$
P^A_i = P_i \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos\theta & \sin\theta \\
0 & -\sin\theta & \cos\theta\\
\end{bmatrix}- P_i 
$$
where $\theta$ denotes a fixed, very small angle.

while $P^B$ (around y-axis) and $P^C$ (around z-axis) can be defined likewise. Rewrite the matrices into vector form $\mathbf{p}^A, \mathbf{p}^B, \mathbf{p}^C$. However, it is easy to find out that the three vectors are generally **NOT** orthogonal.

**2. General approach**

One can generalize the three translations along any orthogonal frame specified by **three Euler angles**, resulting in
$$
\mathbf{p}^X ,  \mathbf{p}^Y ,  \mathbf{p}^Z
$$
associated with 3 parameters.

The three rotations can be also generalized along a frame specified by **three Euler angles**, **around any point for each rotation respectively**. It leads to
$$
\mathbf{p}^A ,  \mathbf{p}^B ,  \mathbf{p}^C
$$
associated with 9 parameters (3 Euler angels + 3 points).

There are totally 15 unknowns and 15 equations (any pair of dot product between the six vectors equals zero). But numeric method gives no solution.

So I am wondering why there is no solution for the general approach. Or is there any theory about such mutual orthogonal transforms?